# How do I get the descendants of a named node using Linq-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<!--Gaffer Tape Regions--> 
  <masks>
   <mask name="Serato">
    <rectangle>
      <xPosition>100</xPosition>
      <yPosition>100</yPosition>
      <height>100</height>
      <width>100</width>
     </rectangle>
     <rectangle>
        <xPosition>500</xPosition>
        <yPosition>500</yPosition>
        <height>100</height>
        <width>100</width>
    </rectangle> 
  </mask>   
  <mask name="Traktor">
    <rectangle>
      <xPosition>180</xPosition>
      <yPosition>70</yPosition>
      <height>200</height>
      <width>300</width>
     </rectangle>
     <rectangle>
        <xPosition>500</xPosition>
        <yPosition>500</yPosition>
        <height>50</height>
        <width>160</width>
    </rectangle>   
  </mask>
 </masks>
```

And I want to retrieve all of the rectangle elements under the mask element whose name is "Serato".

What is the best way to do this in Linq to XML?

**EDIT: Added code that is not working**

Currently trying this:

```
XDocument maskData = XDocument.Load(folderPath + @"\masks.xml");


            var masks =
                    from ma in maskData.Elements("mask")
                    where ma.Attribute("name").Value == "Serato"
                    from rectangle in ma.Elements("rectangle")
                    select rectangle;
```

But the masks query comes back null.

Comment: Tried this: var masks = from m in maskData.Descendants("mask")
                        where (string)m == "Serato"
                        from r in m.Elements("rectangle")
                        select r;

Answer (score 2):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(s);
var rectangles = 
    from mask in xml.Elements("mask")
    where mask.Attribute("name").Value == "Serato"
    from rectangle in mask.Elements("rectangle")
    select rectangle;
```

Comment: I still get a null collection. (Am parsing the xml differently: XDocument maskData = XDocument.Load(folderPath + @"\masks.xml"); but it shows the XML when I watch it

Comment: @Ben: By using XElement.Parse(s), I ended up with an element that represented the root node of the XML you provided. When you load the entire document, its `.Elements()` will only include the root element. You can either change `maskData.Elements("mask")` to `maskData.Descendants("mask")`, or get the `Root` element, as Metro Smurf recommends.

Answer (score 1):

When querying with LINQ to XML, the `Root` node needs to be included. Your edited query will work if you include the Root node:

```
var masks =
    from ma in maskData.Root.Elements( "mask" ) // <-- notice .Root.
    where ma.Attribute( "name" ).Value == "Serato"
    from rectangle in ma.Elements( "rectangle" )
    select rectangle;
```

Or using method chains:

```
var rect = maskData.Root.Elements( "mask" )
        .Where( x => x.Attribute( "name" ).Value == "Serato" )
        .Elements( "rectangle" );
```